# URL rewriting with custom user meta "/%shop_name%/gallery/%gallery%"

Tags: url-rewriting, templates, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite, template-redirect

I have created a custom user meta = `shop_name` in User Profile and custom post type `gallery`

The default URL of the post is `http://localhost/gallery/%gallery%` which i have modified to below given URL using the code given below.

I want my permalink to be in form of `http://localhost/%shop_name%/gallery/%gallery%`.

Every user has a custom user_meta = `shop_name`.

Thus if my user has `shop_name="shop3"` and a gallery whose `title="Washing Machine"` then my user URL should be `http://localhost/shop3/gallery/mashing-machine`

**When i go to** `http://localhost/shop3/gallery/`**I want  all the galleries of** `shop3` **should be listed**. 
 Instead the index page is being shown. 
**How can I make it possible?**

Below is the code which i have written for creating custom url but want to extend it to above mentioned problem.

```
add_action('init', 'tdd_add_rewrite_rules');
function tdd_add_rewrite_rules(){
// Register custom rewrite rules
global $wp_rewrite;
//$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%gallery%', '([^/]+)', 'gallery=');
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%shop_name%', '([^/]+)', 'shop_name=');
 $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('gallery', '/%shop_name%/gallery/%gallery%', false);
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'tdd_permalinks', 10, 3); 
function tdd_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename){ 
$no_data = get_the_author_meta('ID');;
$post_id = $post->ID;
if($post->post_type != 'gallery' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) return $permalink;
// $var1 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'posts_solicitorspeciality', true);
$var1 = get_the_author_meta('shop_name');

$var1 = sanitize_title($var1);
if(!$var1) { $var1 = $no_data; }
  $permalink = str_replace('%shop_name%', $var1, $permalink); 
  // $permalink = str_replace('%post_id%', $post_id, $permalink); 
return $permalink; 
}
```

This is the User Meta - `%shop_name%` which i want to be loaded in URL when viewing posts posted by the Author have shop name - `fila`. I have modified the User Profile settings using ACF to develop this Custom User Settings.
[image]

The Default Permalink Structure.
[image]

Cusotm post - `Gallery` Posted by user with tilte - `gallery 1`
[image]

The `URL` of the Custom Post `gallery` with default permalink structure i.e. `http://localhost/gallery/gallery-1/`
[image]

The `Custom URL` of the Custom Post `gallery` with custom permalink structure using the above code i.e. `http://localhost/fila/gallery/gallery-1/`
[image]

When I go to the URL `http://localhost/fila/gallery/` i want all the **galleries** posted by the **author** with shop_name = `fila` to be displayed , instead the homepage is being shown.
[image]

Similarly when I go to the URL `http://localhost/fila/` i want the **information** of **shop fila** posted by the **author** to be displayed , instead the homepage is being shown.
[image]

Comment: A meta field in URL permastruct? It doesn't sound very intuitive for me. What is supposed that URL should looking for? A page? A custom post type? A user? What is `shoppers-stop` and how are galleries attached to it? Why do you need a meta field in user profile for this?

Comment: @cybmeta i have modified the content...instead of 'shoppers-stop' i have put the name as 'shop1'. i want to display the different galleries posted only by that particular user

Comment: `shoppers-stop`, `shop` or whatever other name doesn't matter. All the others questions I made to you are important to help you. Please, add that information to your question, otherwise I think it is very difficult to give you an answer, at least for me.

Comment: @cybmeta I have modified the post again with screen shots and hope that i have explained it properly this time so that you can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the following functions to solve this problem.

```
   //This adds a custom query variable to the permalink
   function add_custom_query_var( $vars ){
      $vars[] = "shop_name";
      return $vars;
    }
    add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_custom_query_var' );

    function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('shop/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=shop&shop_name=$matches[1]');
    $aNewRules2 = array('shop/([^/]+)/gallery/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=gallery');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aNewRules2 + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
    }
    add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');

    //Here we create a custom permalink structure and replace the shop_name with custom user feild value
    function tdd_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename){ 
        $no_data = get_the_author_meta('ID');;
          $post_id = $post->ID;
        if($post->post_type != 'gallery' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) return $permalink;
        $var1 = get_the_author_meta('shop_name');
        $var1 = sanitize_title($var1);
        if(!$var1) { $var1 = $no_data; }
        $permalink = str_replace('%shop_name%', $var1, $permalink); 
        return $permalink; 
    }
    add_filter('post_type_link', 'tdd_permalinks', 10, 3); 

    function rewrite_flush(){
      global $wp_rewrite;
      $gallery_structure = '/shop/%shop_name%/gallery/%gallery%';
        $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%gallery%", '([^/]+)', "gallery=");
        $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag("%shop_name%", '([^/]+)', "shop_name=");
        $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('gallery', $gallery_structure, false);
      $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
    add_action('init','rewrite_flush');
```